# AspectJ: Issue on Weblogic 12

Tags: java-8, aspectj, weblogic12c, aspectj-maven-plugin

I worked on a Java EE application with following configs:

- JDK 1.7
- AspectJ 1.7
- Weblogic 12.1.3

However, after upgrading the configs to followings, all aspects with "call" wildcards have not worked properly and as a result, no joinpoints, which already hit, can be touched, now:

- JDK Verion: 1.8.0_66
- AspectJ Version: 1.8.7
- Application Server: Weblogic 12.2.1

The aspect snippet is as follows: 


`@Before("call(public * com.gam.commons.core.api.services.Service+.(..)) && within(com.gam.calendar.biz.service.internal.impl.)")
    public void handle(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {

        Class declaringType = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType();
        if (declaringType.isInterface()) {
            UserProfileTO userProfileTO = ((AbstractService) thisJoinPoint.getThis()).getUserProfileTO();/* Caller or this /
            ((Service) thisJoinPoint.getTarget()).setUserProfileTO(userProfileTO);/ Callee or target */
        }
    }`

Now, I am delightfully looking forward in case of any meaningful points you would have for feeding me.

---

***Attention: My problem was due to something else, please look at my answer to glean more information about the issue.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake as my problem was completely due to something else. As I updated my project to be compiled by JDK 1.8.0_66, I should have re-configured aspect-maven-plugin to be compatible with this upgrade. Fortunately, my problem has been solved by re-configuring the appropriate plugin on the POM file, as follows:

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.8</version>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
               <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
               <version>1.8.7</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
               <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
               <version>1.8.7</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>                        
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>                               
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

More info about "aspectj-maven-plugin" is available on [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

Comment: You can accept your own answer in order to close the question.